# Unable to import custom react-three-fiber element even after declaring custom type in react-three-fiber module

Tags: reactjs, typescript, three.js, react-three-fiber

I'm building a react application for visualizing mathematical concepts.  I'm currently using react-three-fiber to build the features.  Since I'm using TypeScript, I found that to build custom ThreeElements (https://docs.pmnd.rs/react-three-fiber/tutorials/typescript), we can extend the custom component to some existing component in three.js module.  I tried following this example:

```js
import { useRef, useEffect } from 'react'
import { GridHelper } from 'three'
import { extend, Object3DNode } from '@react-three/fiber'

// Create our custom element
class CustomElement extends GridHelper {}

// Extend so the reconciler will learn about it
extend({ CustomElement })

// Add types to ThreeElements elements so primitives pick up on it
declare module '@react-three/fiber' {
  interface ThreeElements {
    customElement: Object3DNode<CustomElement, typeof CustomElement>
  }
}

// react-three-fiber will create your custom component and TypeScript will understand it
;<customComponent />
```

However, when I try to import the component like below:

```js
import { customElement } from '@react-three/fiber`
```

I get an error saying that "customElement has no exported member."  Any thoughts on this?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

managed to remove the error by changing the libraries and dependencies with the code sandbox on the tutorial

```
deps{
    "@types/react": "18.0.15",
    "@react-three/fiber": "8.2.2",
    "@types/three": "0.143.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "typescript": "4.7.4",
    "three": "0.143.0"

}
```